# PHP - SQLite3 не записывает данные в бд

Tags: php, sqlite, sqlite3

Работаю с SQLite3 в PHP. Выполняю запрос

```
    INSERT INTO chat(uid, message) VALUES (123456789,'message');
```

Но ничего не добавляется, хотя с другими таблицами все работает нормально.
Вот столбцы в этой таблице:
id - INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.
uid - INTEGER,
message - TEXT

Comment: как именно вы выполняете запрос и отслеживаете ошибки?

Comment: запросы выполняю так $db->query('INSERT INTO db VALUES (111,"111")'); а ошибки так if(!$db->query()){echo 'ошибка';}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть подозрение, что дело в отсутствие AUTOINCREMENT поля ID
попробуйте пересоздать таблицу

```
create table chat
(
  id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  uid INTEGER,
  message TEXT
)
;
```